# blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3 - Connection refused

Tags: node.js, centos, blockchain

I installed blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3 from github and start it

> $ blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000 1460128138018 - info:
>   blockchain.info wallet service v0.19.3 running on 127.0.0.1:3000

but its not listening 3000 port, this

> $ netstat -an | grep 3000

return nothing, and connections to localhost:3000 return "refused"

> $ telnet localhost 3000 Trying ::1... telnet: connect
>   to address ::1: Connection refused Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: connect
>   to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

What I do wrong?

OS: CentOs 6.7

> $ npm version { npm: '3.8.6',   http_parser: '2.3',   modules: '14',
>   node: '0.12.0',   openssl: '1.0.1l',   uv: '1.0.2',   v8: '3.28.73',
>   zlib: '1.2.8' }

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong version of `npm` installed.
From the [installation instructions](http://installation%20instructions):

```
Requires:
node >= 0.12.0
npm >= 2.12.0, < 3.0.0
```